# iterate over string without using string.length

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I wrote that code and I want to iterate over string without using `s.length`.
I can't realize what is the appropriate condition in the while loop.

```
int i = 0;
String s = "abcdefg";
while (s.charAt(i) != null) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `length`?

Comment: Maybe do while(s.charAt(i+1) !=null){

Comment: More accurate - I didn't understand why my code won't work.

Comment: @StreamingBits Like the OP shows.. D:

Comment: `charAt(i)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the index is outside the bounds of the string; it will not return null. Read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile since you're comparing a primitive (char) with `null`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason not to use String's length() method. However, if you must:

```
String s = "abcdefg";
for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Use `char c` not `Character c`. No need to deal with the overhead of wrapper objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could catch the IndexOutOfBounds Exception, which is thrown when you try to read a char Outsider the range oft the string. But using length (if possible?!) would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you can't use length however this solution would work.

```
    int i = 0;
    String s = "abcdefg";
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
             system.out.println(s.charAt(i++));
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is usually discouraged.